# How can I run a single protractor test in IntelliJ?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, protractor

I develop an Angular application and use Protractor for e2e tests. In Intellij (Ultimate Edition) I created a run/debug configuration for my tests. This works fine if I want to run all the tests. But how can I run only a single spec file or a single test case?

I would expect something like when running JUnit tests in Java where I can click into a test method and select from the context menu to only execute this single test method. Is something like that possible with Protractor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either rename the `describe` block to `fdescribe`, and only the tests residing in that block will be run, or rename an `it` block to `fit`, and only this test will get executed.

Comment: Works fine. Thank you.